# How do i make Tailwind css work with .php file?

Tags: php, tailwind-css

I have an issue with tailwind css not working with php files but the same works with html file. When i change the extension to .html it starts working. What shall i do?
I installed tailwind css using npm and followed every step mentioned in the tailwind documentation.
I am new to tailwind css.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Tailwindcss needs to know which files it will process in order to find classes to add to your output css. And you can specify those files in the **tailwind.config.js** file.

In general the `content` section of the configuration file contains `{html,js}`. This tells Tailwindcss to process `.html` and `.js` files

You need to tell tailwindcss that you want it to also process `.php` files by adding `php` to that list making it `{html,js,php}` . (see code below)

```
 /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,php}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The following YouTube video could be of help to you  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPVotANrEYI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Put the cdn in head of your website

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn

EDIT:

You can dowload the script that is showing (CTRL+S) when you go here:
https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.1.8

EDIT:

IF still not working, you can check the console, maybe a cors policy.